# Вконтакте не цепляет изображение с тега image_src

Tags: css, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Почему Vk может не "цеплять" изображение с тега image_src, код ниже

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://diamonddress.ru/images/nofoto.png">
<meta property="og:title" content="Интернет-магазин брендовой женской одежды"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://diamonddress.ru/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://diamonddress.ru/images/nofoto.png"/>
```

Хотя в документации ВК [описан такой метод](http://vk.com/dev/share_details).

Answer (score 2):

https://vk.com/dev/pages.clearCache
Нужно очистить кеш в вк по url.